# Scaling Movement in unity VR with oculus headset

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, visual-studio-2010, virtual-reality

There seems to be an issue when i am using VR. The movement I make is not scaled correctly with the movement in the VR. I have to move much further in reality to go where I need to in VR. I am working on the reach with the OVRgrabbable script after finding something online that may help. I am having an issue with getting the X,Y axis to be recognized as objects. Everything else about the code seems to be ok as nothing else is underlined in red.

[This image is the notif. i am getting. I am just referencing the x and y axis i think it should operate just fine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wSPml.png)

Comment: Please post your code as **text** (formatted as `code`) and if you get any compiler errors include the exact error message you are getting!

Comment: Also `OVRGrabbable` doesn't se to have any member called `delta` ...

Answer (score 1):

I have one suggestion, on the OVRCustomHand.prefab check the configurations on the script OVRCustomSkeleton.cs:

Make sure to [check the checkboxes for](https://developer.oculus.com/documentation/unity/unity-handtracking/?locale=nb_NO) Update Root Pose (only if your OVRHandPrefab is not parented to OVRCameraRig), Update Root Scale (makes the hand model size is scaled either up or down based on the user’s actual hand size), Apply Bone Translation.

[image]

This will make sure the Hand's position is referenced to your scene's global space instead of real tracking space.

Hope it works!